# Bootstrap 3.0 labels don't go inline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some `label`s in a `well`.
I don't know how to make them go to next line.

Here is the unexpected result:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="well">
      <a href="#"><span class="label label-default">Tag name 1</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="label label-primary">Tag name 2</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="label label-warning">Tag name 3</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="label label-danger">Tag name 4</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="label label-info">Tag name 5</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="label label-success">Tag name 6</span></a>
    </div>
```

**update**

Ok, thanks @markthethomas, your respond gave me a tip!

The issue is due to my framework (Rails here) which minimify my html code, removing the supposed unnecessary spaces between each a tag.

Here is a not working demo, without space: http://www.bootply.com/lJJB13ES6V and here is a working demo, the same code but with spaces: http://www.bootply.com/fAOIVSKwaU

Does someone know the reason of this behavior?

Comment: What code is around this? Can you update your question with some more context?

Comment: (i.e. semver for BS and the block(s) surrounding this)

Comment: Without showing your css you will have a hard time getting an answer. What you have shown is only the html and their attributes.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap and I haven't custom CSS here...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is exclusively related to the Bootstrap's `.label` class as already mentioned by @Christina, but in my opinion @Christina is wrong about the fact that the `white-space: nowrap;` will cause the issue described.

The `.label` class set the `display` property to `inline`. Setting this property to `inline-block` will solve your problem correct:

```
.label {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/QqMZzNkQxI

And indeed the issue only happens when there is no white space between the anchor (`a`) tags.

Something similar can be found at: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#labels:

> Rendering problems can arise when you have dozens of inline labels within a narrow container...

Comment: This should be the default style on this element.

Comment: @Christina i don't thinks so. The problem here seems the html minifier that does not respect white space (a space) arround inline elements (span a). For this use case the problem possible can also be fixed by appling the `.label` class on the `a` directly.

Answer (score 1):

`.label` has the style: `white-space: nowrap;`. If your white space is removed, then it will not wrap as you have seen. To add wrap back in but prevent the inside from wrapping:

```
.well .label:after {content:' ';display:inline;white-space:normal}
.well .label {margin-right:2px;}
```

**DEMO: https://jsbin.com/hafeda/1/edit?css,output**

Comment: Your solution works, but in my opinion you should not relate the issue with the `white-space: nowrap;` which prevent only wrapping inside the `.label` itself.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too since it make no sense, but if you change the white-space to normal it starts wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add float: left or bootstrap pull-left (I think that is name) attribute

Attribute option (pull-left):

```
<a href="#"><span class="label label-default pull-left">Tag name 1</span></a>
```

OR CSS option

```
div.well {
  width: 300px, // or whatever width;
 // add rest of well CSS 
} 


a {
  float: left;
  // rest of your a CSS
}
```

Comment: The pull-L/R class doesn't have anything to do with the immediate situation I don't think. Seems to be more of a grid-sizing issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use BS's grid-sizing aspects to control width and overflow of various elements. For example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="well">
          <a href="#"><span class="label label-default">Tag name 1</span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="label label-primary">Tag name 2</span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="label label-warning">Tag name 3</span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="label label-danger">Tag name 4</span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="label label-info">Tag name 5</span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="label label-success">Tag name 6</span></a>
        </div>      
  </div>
</div>
```

will render:

[image]

Here's a link to a jsfiddle example. http://jsfiddle.net/3q3j0uj4/1/

Does that help?

Comment: That almost works, but as you can see (in your own jsfiddle) when you expand to the full screen it makes 2 columns. Kudos for showing the code in action however.

Comment: Worked based on what was provided :) That you aren't using vanilla html and are minifying the html with a framework are quite significant and changed the nature of the question. Adding something about minification in the title would be great.

Comment: you may have mistook me for the poster, I'm just a commenter this time.

Comment: ah! my bad -- doing several things at once. Apologies!

Comment: as far as i understand the grid classes do not solve (and have nothing to do with) the problem described, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3q3j0uj4/4/ which worked as expected.

Comment: yeah; posted this before the poster conveyed new information. It seems to have something do to with how minifcation by the templating engine of choice affects whitespace parsing of the HTML -- or something in that area.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the answer given by Markthethomas, please find the changes for the class in the div

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12">
      <div class="well"> 
        <a href="#"><span class="label label-default">Tag name 1</span></a>
        <a href="#"><span class="label label-primary">Tag name 2</span></a>
        <a href="#"><span class="label label-warning">Tag name 3</span></a>
        <a href="#"><span class="label label-danger">Tag name 4</span></a>
        <a href="#"><span class="label label-info">Tag name 5</span></a>
        <a href="#"><span class="label label-success">Tag name 6</span></a>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Try this and let me know if this solves your issue.